# Qualified Oracle Function Name

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ddl

Hi I have been working with SQL Server for a while. I am on ORacle 11g today though and I am a little lost.

I see an object with the name “Inventory_Part_Config_API.Get_Estimated_Material_Cost(contract, part_no, '*')”.

How can I look at the definition for this function?
Is  Inventory_Part_Config_API a Schema?  A package? A database?  (I am pretty sure Oracle doesn't have 'databases' the same way SQL Server does though.

If Inventory_Part_Config_API is a package, how can I view all the packages? The same for databases.  I know how to view all the schemas and I didn't see this.

Comment: It is most likely a package name.  Query USER_OBJECTS view to see.

Comment: looks like a package to me too...check the packages list in SQL Developer for your user. if it's not there, do an object search using View > Find DB object (or query all_objects or dba_objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inventory_Part_Config_API looks like a package and Get_Estimated_Material_Cost is a procedure inside that package.
If you have PL/SQL developer you can directly go to this package using RMB->View Spec and Body.

If you are using only SQL plus command prompt then you can see the source of the package using following command.

```
Select Text from User_Source where Name Like UPPER('Inventory_Part_Config_API');
```

For both, you need to have the permission to view the package body.

To view the type of any object you can use the SYS.USER_OBJECTS OR ALL_OBJECTS as mentioned in the previous answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you can use `USER_OBJECTS` to see all objects where your user is the owner, in `DBA_OBJECTS` you can see all objects in database, this may not be accessible to you I think, if you don't have sufficient privileges (you need explicit privilege for this view or DBA role). Best way is probably to use `ALL_OBJECTS` there should be listed all object which are accessible by your user. So you can do something like this:

```
SELECT object_type FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE object_name = 'name_of_your_object';
```

If you want to check schemas then use `SELECT * FROM DBA_USERS` every schema is user in Oracle DB.